# Alloy: using "in" and getting error "in can be used only between 2 expressions of the same arity."

Tags: alloy

Here are the signatures

```
one sig Library {
     books: set Book,                                   
     patrons: set Patron,                               
     circulation: Patron lone -> some Book
}

sig Book { }

sig Patron {
    curbooks: set Book
}
```

Question ->What I want to do is : write a fact that the books currently with        a patron are accounted in the library's circulation relation

```
fact curPatronBooksConsistent {
      lone l : Library | all b : l.patrons.curbooks | b in l.circulation
}
```

Now I understand the nature of the error: in can be used only between 2   expressions of the same arity.

```
 Left type = this/Book
 Right type = this/Patron->this/Book
```

However I do not know how to nor can I find any examples of returning only a   "set" of books that are associated with the library.circulation. I realize this  is not a set but a relationship so how do I express that in Alloy?

all the books belonging to the patrons e.g. all p.curbooks are mapped in the l.circulation?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You say

> However I do not know how to nor can I find any examples of returning only a "set" of books that are associated with the library.circulation.

Look again at discussions of the dot (join) operator; you should find plenty of examples.  The relation `circulation` is a ternary relation Library -> Patron -> Book.  Your expression `l.circulation` performs a join and reduces the arity, producing a relation Patron -> Book.

How do you get a relation of the form Patron -> Book down to a set of books?

One obvious way is to join it to a set of Patrons with an expression like `Patron.(l.circulation)`.  That's probably not what you want -- you probably want to say that every book shown as in some patron's `curbooks` is checked out not just to *some* patron but to *that particular* patron.